# Git pull failing due to "local changes" even when there are none?

Tags: git

When I try and pull from origin develop im getting this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    filepath/file
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

However filepath/file is in the git ignore file so when I type `git status` I dont see any changes that I could revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't mind losing my changes to this file I deleted the file, then did `git reset HEAD filepath/file` then `git checkout filepath/file`. This has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to run a

```
git rm --cached filepath/file
```

That will make git "forget" about the file, adding an *already* tracked file to `.gitignore` will not remove it until you run that command also.

(Note this won't actuall `rm` the file)

Comment: fatal: pathspec 'filepath/file' did not match any files

Comment: Did you replace `filepath/file` with your actual file? (Not intended to be insulting, just double checking)

Comment: Yes I did, no offence taken.

Comment: That's . . . odd. Perhaps look into utilizing a GUI interface like SourceTree to see if it can pick out what's really going on?

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is in your .gitignore, you won't see any changes and essentially becomes an untracked file.  Git will prevent overwriting changes as a defensive measure.  (Since any changes made are not recoverable).

I would temporarily remove it from the .gitignore file to see the changes.  Stash or remove the modifications and then do a `git pull`.  Then change the .gitignore to ignore the file again.

Answer (score -3):

what I do with git when something like that happens is open console and start writing all commands that you could type, git commit, git add -a, git push, and then all that again just in case, usually it starts working after that